# Django selenium test failing on form input attribute

Tags: django, selenium, django-testing

Hi I have a Django form where one field is populated depending on the selection of a previous field. This is working fine when manually tested but I'm hitting a bump when testing with selenium.

Here is the failing test:

```
# --- functional tests --- #
class ProjectFormsTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_project_info_form(self):
        ...        
        wind = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_wind_speed')
        self.assertEquals('85', wind.text)
```

So, I can see selenium load up the browser and the field populates as expected. I'm guessing the root of the problem is that `.text` is not the correct attribute for a text input form field, as it is returning `u''`.

Anyone know what is the correct way?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: wind.get_attribute('value') ?

Comment: Ha - that's it! I tried `wind.get_attribute()` AND `wind.value`. If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converted comment:

Use `wind.get_attribute('value')` to get the value attribute of that element.

From [this docs page](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement).